# Convert the following statements into predicate logic.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

G(x) x has a portal gun

R(x) x is a rick

M(x) x is a Morty

Convert the following statements into predicate logic.

1.) There is a Rick.

2.) Everything is a Morty

3.) No morty has a portal gun

How do I even start this? I've watched some videos and it still doesn't click.

1. Rick exists.

R(x)

2. Everything is Morty.

∃x∈M(x)

3. No Morty has a portal gun.

∈M(x)¬G(x)?

Comment: 1. Should be $\exists x R(x)$, does that make sense? $R(x)$ doesn't suffice on its own, since the variable "x" is not specified. By adding $\exists x$ beforehand, you are saying "there is an $x$ satisfying the property $R(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be...

$$1.) \space\space\space\exists x : R(x)$$
$$2.) \space\space\space\forall x : M(x)$$
$$3.) \space\space\space\forall x : M(x)\implies \neg G(x) $$

In plain english these statements would read;

1.) $\space\space$There exists an $x$ such that $x$ has the property of being a Rick.

2.)$\space\space$For all $x$, $x$ has the property of being a Morty.

3.) $\space\space$For all $x$, if $x$ is has the property of being a Morty, then $x$ does not have the property of having a portal gun.

Comment: @AzuraCF (3) "No morty has a portal gun" means "every morty has no portal gun". If this isn't immediately obvious, divide into cases: either the object being discussed is morty, or isn't; if the former, they have no portal gun; if the latter, then no claim is being made; notice that this translates precisely as the given answer above.